# todonotes and verbatim

Tags: verbatim, todonotes

I want to put some comments about actual code into my document, and for that I thought I'd use `\verb` or `\begin{verbatim}`, but it turns out that the `todonotes` package does not like that:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\todo{\verb|Hello!|}

\end{document}
```

Which in turn gives the beautiful error:

```
! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.7 \todo{\verb|Hello!|}
```

A similar problem applies to `\begin{verbatim}`.

So... how do I get verbatim text/code into my todo notes?

Comment: It's not `\todo` that doesn't like `\verb`: `\verb` cannot go in the argument of *any* command. Do you need special characters such as backslash or braces in the "verbatim"?

Comment: Aha, I did not know that, thank you! And yes, I do; the minimal example I gave just doesn't have that. I am commenting on mathematical (source)-code.

Comment: If all you need is monospaced font, you may use `\ttfamily` instead of `\verb`.

Comment: That is not very helpful. As I wrote just above, I need extra symbols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcounter{verbtodo}
\renewcommand{\theverbtodo}{\roman{verbtodo}}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\verbtodo}{v}{%
  \stepcounter{verbtodo}%
  \global\@namedef{verbtodo@\theverbtodo}{#1}%
  \todo{\texttt{\expandafter\protect\csname verbtodo@\theverbtodo\endcsname}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\verbtodo|Hello${okp}^&|

\listoftodos

\end{document}
```

Limitation: the `\listoftodos` command must go at the end of the document. It shouldn't be a big deal.

---

The following more complicated version allows for having `\listoftodos` also at the start.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcounter{verbtodo}
\renewcommand{\theverbtodo}{\roman{verbtodo}}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\verbtodo}{v}{%
  \refstepcounter{verbtodo}\label{verbtodo@\theverbtodo}%
  \global\@namedef{verbtodo@\theverbtodo}{#1}%
  \addtocontents{tdo}{\defineverbtodo{\theverbtodo}|#1|}%
  \todo{\texttt{\expandafter\protect\csname verbtodo@\theverbtodo\endcsname}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\defineverbtodo}{mv}{%
  \@namedef{verbtodo@#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoftodos
\verbtodo|Hello${okp}^&|


\end{document}
```

---

**Limitations** Braces must be balanced and `%` is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you for your effort; I stumbled over fancyvrb, which seems to be nestable in other environments. Do you think this might be a better solution to my problem?

Comment: @mSSM Also the standard `verbatim` can go in other environments, but *not* in *arguments*. The same holds for `Verbatim` from `fancyvrb`.

Comment: Yeah, I actually tried it out after posting my comment, and noticed the same thing. Going to use your solution.