# align* environment cannot be used with todonotes

Tags: todonotes

I am using the package `todolist` with Beamer and it works fine, except when I insert an equation into a todo. The following code:

```
\todo{
    \begin{align*}
        b
    \end{align*}
}
```

gives me the following error:

```
Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }. [\end{frame}]
```

Note that the following code works fine instead

```
\todo{
    \[
        b
    \]
}
```

Why does this occur? Is this issue similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298404/todonotes-and-reserveda-nested-itemize-enumerate-environments)?

Comment: please provide a complete test, it is impossible to debug when you have only shown a fragment of the input and a fragment of the error message, You don't say but I assume given the bit of error that you showed that you are using beamer?

Comment: This doesn't explain why the failure, but you might instead try `$\begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}$`.